# Period stopping hspace

Tags: spacing

For some reason, when I put the period, `\hspace` doesn't do anything (unless it's big enough)

Code:

```
%\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \hspace{-0.21cm}
        \left[\cancelto{\mathbf{0}}{\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\mathbf{x}}} - \bm{\lambda}\right]^{\textrm{T}}_{*,t_f}\delta\mathbf{x}_f + \cancelto{0}{\left[\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} + \mathcal{H}\right]_*}\delta t_f = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_1^*\left(t_f\right) = \lambda_2^*\left(t_f\right) = 0. %Period
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \hspace{-0.21cm}
        \left[\cancelto{\mathbf{0}}{\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\mathbf{x}}} - \bm{\lambda}\right]^{\textrm{T}}_{*,t_f}\delta\mathbf{x}_f + \cancelto{0}{\left[\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} + \mathcal{H}\right]_*}\delta t_f = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_1^*\left(t_f\right) = \lambda_2^*\left(t_f\right) = 0 %No period
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Is there a way to make sure that `\hspace` actually does its job without the period interfering it?

Comment: I tried this on my updated TeXLive 2020 installation. There I am unable to reproduce the behavior with `pdflatex`, but it is there with `lualatex` and `XeLaTeX`. In addition I get the funny error message under `lualatex` : `Class beamer Warning: ``serif'' is obsolete. Use font theme ``serif'' instead on input line 336.`. So +1 for entertainment. ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to say I am using `lualatex` on TeXstudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is explained in the TeXbook. It needs a glob of glue at the beginning of the equation (not negative, unless you want to go in the margin) and a strange glue specification at the end

```
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
```

which will trick TeX into thinking that it has a very very long equation, so it will try to accommodate it by squeezing it into the line. At typesetting time, the large shrinkability makes for normal spacing.

I also changed the `\left`-`\right` pairs  into `\Biggl`-`\Biggr`, so the first brackets are not humongous and the second ones match the height. However, I think that `\biggl`-`\biggr` is the proper size, as shown in the second equation.

```latex
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hspace{0pt}
\Biggl[
  \cancelto{\mathbf{0}}{\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\mathbf{x}}} - \bm{\lambda}
\Biggr]^{\mathrm{T}}_{*,t_f}\delta\mathbf{x}_f
+ \cancelto{0}{\Biggl[\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} + \mathcal{H}\Biggr]_*}\delta t_f
= 0 \rightarrow \lambda_1^*\left(t_f\right) = \lambda_2^*\left(t_f\right) = 0.
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hspace{0pt}
\biggl[
  \cancelto{\mathbf{0}}{\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\mathbf{x}}} - \bm{\lambda}
\biggr]^{\mathrm{T}}_{*,t_f}\delta\mathbf{x}_f
+ \cancelto{0}{\biggl[\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} + \mathcal{H}\biggr]_*}\delta t_f
= 0 \rightarrow \lambda_1^*\left(t_f\right) = \lambda_2^*\left(t_f\right) = 0.
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a good solution! Thank you, will look into it!